# What is the correct time to contact the Editor for a decision when the revisions are elementary

Tags: publications, peer-review, editors

I received a review for my manuscript 6 months after submission.
The reviewer pointed some minor corrections like grammatical errors, missing brackets and so on.

Though I submitted by revisions to the journal 3 weeks back, the Editor  has still not yet given a decision.

The status remained "With Editor" for 2 weeks and now it is "Under Review" for 1 week.

My question is since the errors are elementary, why is the Editor taking so long to check them.
It is evident that it will not take more than an hour to check the revisions.
Then why is the article still "Under Review" for so long.

I am getting really impatient and at the same time afraid about the outcome.
What is the correct time to contact the Editor for a decision when the revisions are elementary?

What are the steps I can take as a author in this kind of situation?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your opening line is unnecessarily polemic. You might as well write "how dare Editors take summer holidays?"

Answer (score 2):

> What are the steps I can take as a author in this kind of situation?

Be patient. Your editor may be:

1. Busy.
2. On vacation. It's summer, many academics vacation then.
3. On vacation, but while being on vacation also busily preparing for (or already started) the upcoming semester, especially during a tumultuous pandemic where they may not know if they are teaching classes in-person or online.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, When do you think is the correct time to contact the Editor in this type of situation?

Comment: @Math_Freak see [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/56594). If your revision went for peer review, then it's one situation. But before several months (2-3), there is unlikely there is any reason to contact the editor.